# SnowFlake and S3 MetaData

Tags: amazon-s3, metadata, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have custom metadata properties on my s3 files such as:

- x-amz-meta-custom1:  "testvalue"
- x-amz-meta-custom2:  "whoohoo"

When these files are loaded into SnowFLake, how do I access the custom properties associated with the files.  Google and SnowFlake documentation haven't turned up any gems yet.

Comment: Hi - can you clarify what you mean by "loaded into Snowflake"? Do you mean a stage has been created over the files in S3 or do you mean the data has been loaded from S3 into Snowflake tables?

Comment: Those are S3 metadata tags.  Snowflake is ingesting the data contained in the bucket, but doesn't consume the metainformation of the bucket itself.  How are you loading the files into snowflake?

Answer (score 0):

Based on docs, I think the only metadata that you can access via the stage is filename and row number.  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-metadata.html
You could possibly write something custom that picks up the S3 metadata and writes out a s3 filename along with the metadata and then ingest that back into another snowflake table.